# Need a good way using Delphi to 'rotate' (pivot?) data in a flat table

Tags: database, delphi, pivot

I have a data table with records that have a repeated field 'position' - imagine a rotating table with 4 positions each numbered 1 to 4 inc. I store 4 database table rows for each rotation and each row contains the rotation position 1 to 4 inc, so this position field goes 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2 etc. An example would be:

```
Position  Field1 Field2 Field3
------------------------------
1         4.5    4.6    1.4 
2         5.5    3.6    2.4
3         4.5    7.6    3.4
4         7.5    2.6    4.4
1         2.5    3.6    5.4
2         3.5    9.6    6.4
3         9.5    3.6    7.4
4         1.5    6.6    8.4
1         2.5    9.6    9.4
```

I would like to display a grid (or generate a table) that has the position field 1,2,3,4 along the top (columns) and each of my other original data fields (that were the columns) now as rows. From the above example this would be:

```
        1        2        3        4
        ------------------------------
Field1  2.5      3.5      9.5      1.5
Field2  9.6      9.6      3.6      6.6
Field3  9.4      6.4      7.4      8.4
```

I require that only the last 4 data entries are displayed and I believe that this is a kind of pivot? I have Developer Express' Quantum Grid so I can easily add their pivot suite if needed. My requirement is that this should be very fast and only display the last 4 positions, not sums or other aggregates. Can I code this in a fast way? Is it something that a reporting tool can do? Or should I use the pivot suite solution?

Comment: @Ken: Yes, sorry, my first post to SO using an iPad :( IOS is not always a panacea!

Comment: Is that a `TDataSet` you have?

Comment: If you use a Sql server 2008 then pivot it in the sql script

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt to make a solution that I think it's fast:

```
//
//  set alignment to 4 bytes, we will need it that way for later
//
{$A4}
type
  TMyRecord = record
    Position: Integer;
    Field1: Double;
    Field2: Double;
    Field3: Double;
  end;

const
  szMyRecord = SizeOf(TMyRecord);

const
  CMYRECORD_LIST: array[0..8] of TMyRecord = (
    (Position: 1; Field1: 4.5; Field2: 4.6; Field3: 1.4),
    (Position: 2; Field1: 5.5; Field2: 3.6; Field3: 2.4),
    (Position: 3; Field1: 4.5; Field2: 7.6; Field3: 3.4),
    (Position: 4; Field1: 7.5; Field2: 2.6; Field3: 4.4),
    (Position: 1; Field1: 2.5; Field2: 3.6; Field3: 5.4),
    (Position: 2; Field1: 3.5; Field2: 9.6; Field3: 6.4),
    (Position: 3; Field1: 9.5; Field2: 3.6; Field3: 7.4),
    (Position: 4; Field1: 1.5; Field2: 6.6; Field3: 8.4),
    (Position: 1; Field1: 2.5; Field2: 9.6; Field3: 9.4)
  );

const
  CDELTA = 4; // last 4 records
  CCOLUMNS = 4; // columns for target grid

procedure|function...
type
  //
  //  used for accessing our record Fields from 1 to 3 as array
  //
  TMyRecordHack = array[0..2] of Double;

const
  szInteger = SizeOf(Integer);

var
  Index: Integer;
  kIndex: Integer;
  LStartIndex: Integer;
  LRecFields: TMyRecordHack;
  LRecAddr: Integer;
  LMyListAddr: Integer;
  LCol: Integer;
  LRow: Integer;
begin
  LStartIndex := Length(CMYRECORD_LIST) - CDELTA;
  //
  //  store address of first record
  //
  LMyListAddr := Integer(@CMYRECORD_LIST[Low(CMYRECORD_LIST)]);
  //
  //  store the address of TMyRecord at LStartIndex
  //
  LRecAddr :=
    //
    //  CMYRECORD_LIST base address
    //
    LMyListAddr +
    //
    //  record address is RecordIndex * szMyRecord
    //
    LStartIndex * szMyRecord +
    //
    //  skip Position member of TMyRecord
    //
    szInteger;
  for Index := LStartIndex to High(CMYRECORD_LIST) do begin
    //
    //  convert address into pointer and cast pointer as TMyRecordHack
    //
    LRecFields := TMyRecordHack( Ptr( LRecAddr )^ );
    LCol := CMYRECORD_LIST[ Index ].Position;
    for kIndex := Low(LRecFields) to High(LRecFields) do begin
      //
      //  +1 required, we're using a string grid
      //
      LRow := kIndex +1;
      //
      //  display data
      //
      StringGrid1.Cells[ LCol, LRow ] := FloatToStr( LRecFields[ kIndex ] );
    end; // for kIndex := Low(LRecFields) to High(LRecFields) do begin
    //
    //  increment LRecAddr by szMyRecord
    //
    Inc(LRecAddr, szMyRecord);
  end; // for Index := LStartIndex to High(CMYRECORD_LIST) do begin
end;
```

OK, TMyRecordHack may not be the best name, but you can call it whatever you want (: